# Remove automatically generated color key in Gadfly plot?

Tags: plot, julia, gadfly

I'm just starting out with Julia and trying to create a simple sin/cos plot using [Gadfly](http://gadflyjl.org/). It all works well, however for some reason Gadfly insists on inserting its own `Color... f1 f2` legends into the plot (see the red-outlined portion in the image). Could anyone please tell me what I should do to remove it? I've searched but couldn't find anything. The code that generates this is given below.

I'm using Julia 0.4.6 on Windows 10.

[image: Plot Output]

```
using Gadfly

set_default_plot_size(9inch, 9inch/golden)

πs = Char(960) # pi in string form
ticklabel_data = ["$πs/2", πs, "3$πs/2", "2$πs", "5$πs/2"]

global c = 0
incr = () -> global c = (c + 1) % 5 == 0? 1 : (c + 1) % 5
ticklabels = () -> ticklabel_data[incr()]

plot([sin, cos],
     0, 2 * pi,
     Guide.xticks(ticks=[pi/2, pi, 3 * pi / 2, 2 * pi]),
     Scale.x_continuous(labels = x -> @sprintf "%s" ticklabels()),
     Guide.manual_color_key("Color", ["sin", "cos"], ["#D4CA3A", "deepskyblue"])
)
```

Comment: From a glance at the docs, I'll guess that `manual_color_key` is used only when you're displaying a plot with two layers and you want to combine them with a single key. Here, you've only got one layer. You might also want to glance at Plots.jl, which has more extensive documentation...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be because you're plotting "two things", as opposed to "one thing" with two layers.

Try:

```
plot(
    layer(sin, 0, 2 * pi, Theme(default_color=colorant"#D4CA3A")), 
    layer(cos, 0, 2 * pi, Theme(default_color=colorant"deepskyblue")),
    Guide.xticks(ticks=[pi/2, pi, 3 * pi / 2, 2 * pi]),
    Scale.x_continuous(labels = x -> @sprintf "%s" ticklabels()),
    Guide.manual_color_key("Color", ["sin", "cos"], ["#D4CA3A", "deepskyblue"])
)
```