# How to change the color key using Gadfly's `Scale.color_discrete_manual` in Julia?

Tags: plot, syntax, julia, gadfly

I have imported a `DataFrame` as below:

```
julia> df
100×3 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ ex1     │ ex2     │ admit │
├─────┼─────────┼─────────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ 34.6237 │ 78.0247 │ 0     │
│ 2   │ 30.2867 │ 43.895  │ 0     │
│ 3   │ 35.8474 │ 72.9022 │ 0     │
│ 4   │ 60.1826 │ 86.3086 │ 1     │
│ 5   │ 79.0327 │ 75.3444 │ 1     │
│ 6   │ 45.0833 │ 56.3164 │ 0     │
│ 7   │ 61.1067 │ 96.5114 │ 1     │
│ 8   │ 75.0247 │ 46.554  │ 1     │
⋮
│ 92  │ 90.4486 │ 87.5088 │ 1     │
│ 93  │ 55.4822 │ 35.5707 │ 0     │
│ 94  │ 74.4927 │ 84.8451 │ 1     │
│ 95  │ 89.8458 │ 45.3583 │ 1     │
│ 96  │ 83.4892 │ 48.3803 │ 1     │
│ 97  │ 42.2617 │ 87.1039 │ 1     │
│ 98  │ 99.315  │ 68.7754 │ 1     │
│ 99  │ 55.34   │ 64.9319 │ 1     │
│ 100 │ 74.7759 │ 89.5298 │ 1     │
```

I want to plot this `DataFrame` using `ex1` as x-axis, `ex2` as y-axis. In addition, the data is categorized by the third column `:admit`, so I want to give dots different colors based on the `:admit` value.

I used `Scale.color_discrete_manual` to set up colors, and I tried to use `Guide.manual_color_key` to change the color key legend. However it turns out Gadfly made two color keys.

```
p = plot(df, x = :ex1, y = :ex2, color=:admit,
         Scale.color_discrete_manual(colorant"deep sky blue",
                                     colorant"light pink"),
         Guide.manual_color_key("Legend", ["Failure", "Success"],
                                ["deep sky blue", "light pink"]))
```

[image: plot1]

My question is how to change the color key legend when using `Scale.color_discrete_manual`?

One related question is [Remove automatically generated color key in Gadfly plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38615552/remove-automatically-generated-color-key-in-gadfly-plot), where the best answer suggests to use two layers plus `Guide.manual_color_key`. Is there a better solution for using `DataFrame` and `Scale.color_discrete_manual`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, it looks like users cannot customize the color legend generated by `color` or `Scale.color_discrete_manual` based on the [discussion](https://github.com/GiovineItalia/Gadfly.jl/issues/940).

From the same source, [Mattriks](https://github.com/Mattriks) suggested to use an extra column as "label". Although it is not "natural" for changing color key, it works pretty well.

Therefore, for the same dataset in the problem. We add one more column:

```
df[:admission] = map(df[:admit])do x
    if x == 1
        return "Success"
    else
        return "Failure"
    end
end

julia> df
100×4 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ exam1   │ exam2   │ admit │ admission │
├─────┼─────────┼─────────┼───────┼───────────┤
│ 1   │ 34.6237 │ 78.0247 │ 0     │ "Failure" │
│ 2   │ 30.2867 │ 43.895  │ 0     │ "Failure" │
│ 3   │ 35.8474 │ 72.9022 │ 0     │ "Failure" │
│ 4   │ 60.1826 │ 86.3086 │ 1     │ "Success" │
│ 5   │ 79.0327 │ 75.3444 │ 1     │ "Success" │
│ 6   │ 45.0833 │ 56.3164 │ 0     │ "Failure" │
│ 7   │ 61.1067 │ 96.5114 │ 1     │ "Success" │
│ 8   │ 75.0247 │ 46.554  │ 1     │ "Success" │
⋮
│ 92  │ 90.4486 │ 87.5088 │ 1     │ "Success" │
│ 93  │ 55.4822 │ 35.5707 │ 0     │ "Failure" │
│ 94  │ 74.4927 │ 84.8451 │ 1     │ "Success" │
│ 95  │ 89.8458 │ 45.3583 │ 1     │ "Success" │
│ 96  │ 83.4892 │ 48.3803 │ 1     │ "Success" │
│ 97  │ 42.2617 │ 87.1039 │ 1     │ "Success" │
│ 98  │ 99.315  │ 68.7754 │ 1     │ "Success" │
│ 99  │ 55.34   │ 64.9319 │ 1     │ "Success" │
│ 100 │ 74.7759 │ 89.5298 │ 1     │ "Success" │
```

Then color the data using this new column `Scale.color_discrete_manual`:

```
plot(df, x = :exam1, y = :exam2, color = :admission,
     Scale.color_discrete_manual(colorant"deep sky blue",
                                 colorant"light pink"))
```

[image: plot]